# Iterating through an arraylist of sets

Tags: java, loops, iterator, iteration

I'm currently trying to iterate through an arraylist of sets that contain strings. It looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Set<String>> e = new ArrayList<Set<String>>(Size);

    for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
        for(Object obj: e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to access and modify the strings inside the set (Printed beforehand to see if it worked), but I can't find a way to get to them. Any ideas?

Comment: The only way to change the content of the Sets is to remove or add elements to it. You can't change an existing element of the Set.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, can you show an input output example please?

Comment: @YCF_L said exactly what i was thinking.

Comment: @Eran: Of course you can change an element inside a `Set`! But then this element must not be immutable (Strings are immutable …), and when the change would have an effect on the results of `equals()`, `hashCode()` and/or the compare method of an eventual comparator, it may kill your set's structure. So it is usually considered a bad idea to modify elements of a set in-place – but it is possible …

Comment: @tquadrat I meant that you can't replace an element in the Set (unlike a List where you have a `E set(int index, E element)` method to replace an element at a given position).

Comment: @Eran: Perhaps you meant that, but that's not what you said 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify a String; if you want to change one of the Strings in the `Set`s, you have to remove it and to add the new one.

Regarding the (simple) iteration:

```
for( var set : e )
{
  for( var string : set )
  {
     out.println( string );
  }
}
```

If you want to change the contents of your data structure:

```
for( var set : e )
{
  Set<String> newStrings = new HashSet<>();
  for( var i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
  {
    var string = i.next();
    if( isInvalid( string ) )
    { 
      i.remove();
      newStrings.add( calculateNewString( string ) );
    } 
  }
  set.addAll( newStrings );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<Set<String>> e = new ArrayList(size);
//Fill your sets with data here

for(Set<String> set : e) { //Iterate through the Arraylist getting every set
    for(String element : set) { //Iteretae through the current Set getting every String
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey I can help you with the accessing part, therefore you shuold use a foreach loop like this

```
ArrayList<Set<String>> e = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();

    for (Set<String> oneSet : e) {

        for (String oneString : oneSet) {

            oneString
            //do something...
        }
    }
```